# My H1 div with the ID #firstheader will not Fade Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to coding and I'm so excited to learn everything I can. Currently, though, there is a problem. I would like my first heading to fade out, but it will absolutely not work. Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeOut('slow', 500);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Global HypeBeast: Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is really stumping me.

Comment: My bad, I edited it to say FadeOut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)** take `slow/fast` or duration instead not the both in the same time so :

```
$("#firstheader").fadeOut('slow');
```

Or :

```
$("#firstheader").fadeOut(500);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Global HypeBeast: Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you check the documentation for fadeOut : 
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

It seems that you can either say 'slow', or put a duration manually :)

Cheers,

Edit: modifying my answer according to Rory McCrossan true comment.

Comment: `fadeOut()` can accept multiple arguments, but only 1 duration :)

Comment: Oh, my bad, wrote too fast. It takes 2 arguments, but even after reading the doc, it still doesn't make sense to me to put both 'slow' and a duration ?

Comment: It doesn't work if you put both .fadeOut('slow', 500), it throws error Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function(…). Either fadeOut('slow') or fadeOut(500) not both. Easing should be swing, linear or other plugins. There is no easing "500".

Comment: Yup, there was a misunderstanding, Rory was pointing out the fact that I first said that it was taking only one argument, which was wrong, I was speaking about one duration argument but it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) doesn't take two speed arguments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstheader">
  <h1>Global HypeBeast: Street Fashion WORLDWIDE</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the `h1` element but you have faded out the container div. Instead do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader h1").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

and in the css:

```
#firstheader h1{
   display:none;
}
```

---

As the question is been edited to `fadeOut` instead of `fadeIn`:

```
   $("#firstheader h1").fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: The CSS is unnecessary and applying fadeOut on a parent will affect it's children. The real problem here is the OP had invalid arguments.

Comment: What if there are other elements along with h1. then all will be affected.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the way you are stating it seems to imply that's part of the problem on why OP code is not working.